# How to transform dictionary in array of documents in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have this following object:

```
var d = { 
  "restaurant": 20, 
  "hotel": 40, 
  "travel": 60 
}
```

And I need to transform it into this:

```
var a = [
{ 
  "category_name": "restaurant",
  "amount": 20
},
{ 
  "category_name": "hotel",
  "amount": 40
},
{ 
  "category_name": "travel",
  "amount": 60
}
]
```

This might be a silly question but as I am not a programmer I am facing this issue. Could some one help me at least pointing a direction for me to follow?

Comment: note that `var d = { "restaurant": 20, "hotel": 40, "hotel": 60 }` will be equal to `var d = { "restaurant": 20, "hotel": 60 }` as there is no point of having duplicated keys in object, later one just overrides the former one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Object.keys(d).map(k=>({"category_name": k, "amount": d[k]}))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just updated the question because I forgot to sum one of the values, but I will try your answer to get unstuck.

Comment: `key` of object is unique so your object is not correct, so you can't do operations on it, but if you want to fix it you can do something like this `var d = { 
  "restaurant": 20, 
  "hotel": [40, 60],  
}` @LucasRezende

Comment: I just got the proper output result that I should have put on the question description. Now that's right and thank you for the help! All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` and `reduce` with `Object.entries`:

```
var a = Object.entries(Object.entries(d).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
    (acc[k] = acc[k] || 0) += parseInt(v);
    return acc;
}, {})).map(([k, v]) => ({ category_name: k, amount: v }));
```

Comment: not summing the hotel amount values

Comment: It won't since you cant have multiple same `keys` in object :) the question is incorrect

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't see that - therefore my first answer was correct?

Comment: Updated the question description and now that's right. Thank you for the tip.